# How can I make a 2 column layout with flex in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently I've a flex layout with 2 columns. But the problem is, that I need to set the width of the left column to the width of the max width left column that exists. How can I do this?

```css
p {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    line-height: 2;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Test 1</span>
    <span>Content 1</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Test test test test test</span>
    <span>Content test test test</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Test test 2</span>
    <span>Content 1</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Test blub</span>
    <span>abc</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your initial question doesn't appear to match up well with the code you've provided as an example. Perhaps provide a link to a working demonstration of your desired outcome, or spend a few more minutes refining the text of your question to be even more clear? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

And in your css:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
}
```

Bootstrap (4) has solved this issue by using row and col class names.

Comment: And if you need to fix the width of the left column, you can have the right column grow by using `flex-grow: 1;` to the right column. this will fill the remaining space that the left column doesn't take up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS table layout not a flexbox layout:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table p {
  display: table-row;
  line-height: 2;
}

.table p span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <p>
    <span>Test 1</span>
    <span>Content 1</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Test test test test test</span>
    <span>Content test test test</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Test test 2</span>
    <span>Content 1</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Test blub</span>
    <span>abc</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When I add now a padding-bottom to the p the padding goes inside the p

Comment: @Mr.Jo you need to add it to the span, no p because it's a table-row now

Comment: Would it not be semantically much better to use an actual table for a tabular layout? It may depend on the data, but I feel like it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @anonymouscoward I would avoid the use of `table` to be able to change the layout when needed. Actually it's tabular but we may decide something else on small screens. So semantically it may not be always a table